# Deque using doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, deque

I was trying to implement a deque using a singly LL when I realized that `eject()` (popping the tail element) wasn't going to work without a pointer to the previous element.

A few implementations I've seen online seem to use a node `struct` as well as a queue `struct`, so I'm starting to think I might've really messed this thing up (although it somehow seems to work).

I'm only including the 4 main functions;
`push()` `pop()` `inject()` and `eject()`.

Any feedback is welcome.
A few things on my mind besides optimization issues:
how would you test the robustness of something like this? I ran tests "manually" but clearly nothing exhaustive. Also I wanted to return an actual value for `pop()` and `eject()` instead of just printing it, but I'm not sure what to do when the list is empty. As of right now I end up returning zero with a message, but that feels...not amazing.

**EDIT**: This is obviously a lot of code but`pop()/eject()` and `push()/inject()` are very similar; so if you don't have time to look at the whole thing, feedback on `pop()` and `push()` would already be great, or even just one of them.

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;      
    struct node* next;
    struct node* previous;      
}node;

node* head = NULL;
node* tail = NULL;

int head_value();
int tail_value();
void push(int);
int pop();
void inject(int);
int eject();

int size = 0;

void push(int value)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {       
        head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->value = value;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->previous = NULL;
        tail = head;
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next = head;
        new_node->next->previous = new_node;
        head = new_node;
        new_node->previous = NULL;
        size++;     
    }   
}

int pop()
{   
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List Empty\n");     
        return 0;
    }

    node* temp = head;
    int value = temp->value;        
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
    if (head != NULL)
        head->previous = NULL;
    size--;
    if (size == 0)
        tail = NULL;
    return value;
}

void inject(int value)
{
    if (tail == NULL)
    {               
        tail = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tail->value = value;
        tail->next = NULL;
        tail->previous = NULL;
        head = tail;
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));      
        new_node->value = value;
        tail->next = new_node;
        new_node->previous = tail;
        tail = new_node;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        size++;
    }
}

int eject()
{
    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        printf("List Empty\n");     
        return 0;
    }

    int value = tail->value;
    node* temp = tail;
    tail = temp->previous;
    free(temp);
    if (tail != NULL)
        tail->next = NULL;
    size--; 
    if (size == 0)
        head = NULL;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`This [looks] a lot of code but pop()/eject() and push()/inject() are very similar`
- due to code duplication!

- don't write, never publish uncommented/undocumented code
- don't leave "allocation values" unchecked
  OK, so C's exception handling is nothing to speak of, and trying to illuminate *not repeating oneself*, I fail to usefully handle allocation failure below.
  (There's advice to not check for error conditions one doesn't know how to handle - seems to be conflicting)
- don't repeat yourself:
  separate things common from things differing and
  reuse common things

  ```
  …
  /** prepend value */
  void push(int value)
  {
      if (tail != (head = add_node(value))) {
          head->next->previous = head;
          head->previous = NULL;
      }
  }
  static const node _dummy;
  static node* add_node(int value) {
      node* const new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
      if (NULL == new_node) {
          printf("malloc failed\n");     
          return &_dummy;  /* ?!? */
      }
      new_node->next = head;
      new_node->value = value;
      new_node->previous = tail;
      size += 1;

      if (NULL == head)
          head = tail = new_node;
      return new_node;
  }
  /** append value */
  void inject(int value)
  {
      if (head != (tail = add_node(value))) {
          tail->previous->next = tail;
          tail->next = NULL;
      }
  }

  /** extract head value
   *  returns 0 if no value held */
  int pop()
  {
      const node* doomed = head;
      if (NULL != head) {
          head = head->next;
          if (head != NULL)
              head->previous = NULL;
      }
      return extract(doomed);
  }
  static int extract(node *doomed) {
      if (NULL == node) {
          printf("List Empty\n");     
          return 0;  /* ?!? */
      }
      int value = doomed->value;
      free(doomed);
      if (--size <= 0)
          head = tail = NULL;
      return value;
  }
  /** extract tail value */
  int eject()
  {
      const node* doomed = tail;
      if (NULL != tail) {
          tail = tail->previous;
          if (tail != NULL)
              tail->next = NULL;
      }
      return extract(doomed);
  }
  ```

  (caveat: I neither even tried to compile this, nor did I code C "in anger" for a quarter of a century.)